# The type for namespace name 'FormHome' could be not be found {are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference}

Tags: c#, assemblies

[image]

there is no place for assemlbies in my project. I tried many methods to find it, but without success.

Comment: Please share the actual code instead of images.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2022

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it can't find the class - it's not in the same namespace as your current code.
That may be it's in a different project in the current solution, in a external DLL, or just in a different namespace in another file in the current project.

Start by hovering the mouse over the error, and open the drop down that appears. If it has an "include" option, click that, and it should fix it.
If it doesn't, you need to find out where that class is, and add a reference to uit, either via the project in the same solution, or via the DLL, and then add the appropriate using line to the top of all files that reference it.

Comment: but the main problem in my project is there is no place for assemblies. how can i add it?